# TableView is not responsive to touch

Tags: swift, xcode

When I run the application with `Command + R`, the `tableView` responds normally, but when I exit the application and reopen it, the `cells` do not respond when I tap the tableView.

This problem did not occur when I ran the same code in an application I created as a test.

This problem only occurs in the production application.
My guess is that the problem is on the configuration side of the application. However, I do not know where the problem is.

### code

---

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TableViewMT: UITableView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
extension TableViewMT: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        
        cell.layoutMargins = .zero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

If you have any idea of this problem, please let me know.

My environment:
Xcode 13.4
iOS 15.4

My native language is not English, so there may be mistakes in the text.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, define "exit the application and reopen it": do you kill it from the app switcher or just go to the home screen and then back to the app?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I have edited my question. Also, the definition of "quit and reopen the application" is to press the home button twice, scroll up the application and kill it. Also reopen it again. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you provided that can hint to a root cause of the problem. What else is on screen except the table view? It might be another view obstructing the table view, a gesture recognizer intercepting the events etc.

Comment: Only the tableView is addedSubView to the view controller, so it does not overlap with others. Also, the tableView is responding to scrolling.
Thank you very much for your detailed response.

Comment: If you remove the line `cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, does it help?

Comment: That did not seem to be the issue.
The problem is in the app settings. I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Without looking at more of your code, it's hard to guess what's causing that. If you observe the issue only in the production build on the device and it's easily reproducible, add some extra logging using `os_log` or the `Logger` API (don't use `print`s, they won't be useful), then connect the device to a Mac with a cable, launch Console.app and monitor the app logs in real time there. May be that will give some clues. Definitely try to check if the delegate's method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response.
I will try your method.

Comment: I monitored the log and could not find the problem, so I stopped using tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:), created a custom class for tableViewCell and put touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) inside it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Added the following code to tableViewCell.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //Code
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).